# EXCEPT returning unpredictable results

Tags: sql, sql-server, except

I have a table `DB_Budget` which has 3 columns `Business_Unit_Code`, `Ledger_Period`, `Budget_GBP`. For sake of simplicity, I have left out the other columns.

Data types are -

[image]

This table is present in my development and production environment.

While doing some quality checks I ran the below query:

```
select 
Business_Unit_Code,
Ledger_Period,
Budget_GBP
from [SomeLinkedServer].[Database].dbo.DB_BUDGET
where business_unit_code = 'AV' and ledger_period = '200808'
and budget_gbp >= 32269

except

select 
Business_Unit_Code,
Ledger_Period, 
Budget_GBP
from [Database].dbo.DB_BUDGET
where business_unit_code = 'AV' and ledger_period = '200808'
and budget_gbp >= 32269
```

I got this -

[image]

If I remove the except, this is what I get -

[image]

Clearly, data is same in both tables! Why would `EXCEPT` give me one row?

Things get interesting. I wrap `Budget_GBP` around `LTRIM(RTRIM( ...` construct. 
And things matched!

I did a bit of `googling` and found that `LTRIM(RTRIM(` basically rounds off the float to `32269.2`. That might be the reason why they match.

So, to summarize, my **first** question is why the `EXCEPT` gives a row in result when the records are matching?

My **second** question might be simple. As you can see, I am restricted to use the clause `budget_gbp >= 32269` in `WHERE` clause. Reason is when I provide the exact value(which I am copying from SSMS), I get no results. Please let me know what I am doing wrong here.

**EDIT**  - Is there any way the data validation might work? There are 100s of table in the database and it is next to impossible for me to scavenge for float columsn and wrap them around cast. Using EXCEPT is one ways of validating the data in development environment.

Comment: @dnoeth the question of course is a field like "Budget" really should have been am approximate value or not.

Comment: @Conrad Frix: Yep, as a consequence one should consider switching to exact numbers :-)

Comment: As @dnoeth is hinting, are you using a `number` or `decimal` type to store the `Budget_GBP` values?  If not, you are likely using a floating number that is stored/calculated similar to scientific notation, where you are likely to have unexpected things happen.  Another possibility is that a string value may have a space at the end of the value.  E.g., `Ledger_Period` may actually be `200808 `.  You could also try checking the length of the value-- I had a case where a non-visible char was stored in a varchar field. It looked like an empty string, but comparing it to '' was always false.

Comment: If you go through my question entirely, you would see, the field is a `float`. I am interested in the `unexpected things happen` part.

Comment: @dnoeth - excellent link(Though I am no good at maths!) Made me come across the wiki link to Failure at Dhahran `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIM-104_Patriot#Failure_at_Dhahran`. Makes me appreciate the work we do.

Comment: Are you just trying to find records that don't exist in the *Dev* environment v's *Production* environment?

Comment: ^^ yes, and the opposite as well.

Comment: You could use a tool like *Data Compare, Red-Gate*

Comment: Don't have that luxury :(

Comment: For floats / singles / doubles (e.g. 'approximate values') vs money / decimal / int / *<whatever-fixed-point>* have a look at [this video](https://vimeo.com/7403673) around the 6:00 mark.

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti, it's free for 14 days :)

Comment: I would say this question should be closed, as datatype mismatches are inherently unpredictable when compared, and are thus predictable, negating the context of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Cast the values to fixed point types or strings and re-run your code.  The first query would look like:

```
select Business_Unit_Code, Ledger_Period, cast(Budget_GBP as decimal(18, 2)) as Budget_GBP
```

With numbers, what you see is not always what you get.  So you see 32669.19, but it might really be 32.669.189999.

Comment: `Seems to me that the float data type is evil` You should've thought of that before; [it's not as if this information is new or anything](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems) ;-) Floats have their uses but *not* for monetary values. The 'quick fix' is the cast, the *actual* fix is changing all floats to money/decimal. Have a look at [this](https://vimeo.com/7403673) around the 6:00 mark. [If you understand what you're doing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) floats aren't *that* evil.

Comment: This is legacy DB. I have no control over the data types. I am looking to shoot the developer though :)

Answer (score 2):

you could define an accuracy and check if the value is within the specified accuracy of each other.

```
declare @accuracy  float = 0.001

select * 
  from      DB_BUDGET1 t1
  full join DB_BUDGET2 t2 
    on  t1.Business_Unit_Code=t2.Business_Unit_Code
    and t1.Ledger_Period     =t2.Ledger_Period
    and t1.Budget_GBP between t2.Budget_GBP-@accuracy  and t2.Budget_GBP+@accuracy 
  where t1.id is null
     or t2.id is null
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/41da0/2/0